# No Source-Map Requests

Tags: httprequest, source-maps, developer-tools

There are several ways a browser gets a source map:

1. Comment at the bottom of a file, with the entire sourcemap content.
2. Comment at the bottom of a file, pointing to a URL, which returns the sourcemap content. Usually this is a file ending in `.map`, but theoretically it could be dynamically generated.
3. Header pointing to a source map URL.

As you can see, 2 & 3 require HTTP requests. However, I have never seen Firefox or Chrome show a source map request in their respective "Network" tabs. I believe Internet Explorer doesn't support source maps, and I haven't tested often enough on Edge or Safari, or Opera. Mobile browsers typically don't have dev tools at all, which is a shame, but I digress.

Why don't Firefox and Chrome show the source map requests? I don't see why they wouldn't know there is a source map, and where it comes from. Is this not a popular enough feature? Do developers usually use option 1, so the browser vendors never felt the need to add this? I would assume it doesn't depend on how you add the source maps. Maps added via Ruby on Rails look the same as ones added via gulp or webpack, and the comments and headers looks the same, as this is an open standard.

For what it's worth, my company likes keeping things close to the vest, as most companies do, so we use URLs. We use the header as this way the same file can be served in development and production, and the server can just not add the header in production. This way it is harder to see the true source code, and all you get is the minified, mangled release code. This may be security through obscurity, but it's easy enough to add, so I say why not? I have tried option 2, though, and still didn't see the requests in the network tab.

**Why don't browsers show HTTP requests for source maps?**